# Why two loops in Programming Languages?

Tags: loops, for-loop, programming-languages, while-loop

Since I started learning programming, In every language i learn, there's always a `while` loop and `for` loop.

As `while` can do all those thing which `for` loop can. Both perfoms the same functionality to iterate. then what was the purpose of adding a `for` loop?

Is there any performance difference in using them? Why there are two loops in every language?

Comment: Why not? Why not give programmers different ways to do things?

Comment: I am not saying not to give them option. But is there any purpose to give them two option?

Comment: If there are different ways to do things, that means no one came up with "the one right way."  I think this is a good question, why *is* there no "one right way"?

Comment: Sure - however, this is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.".

Comment: @Oded: I think, only here I can get the right answer.

Comment: It still doesn't make it a suitable question, sorry.

Comment: Technically, you can do everything you need to be able to do using a few rather primitive operations (assembly language or a portable variation thereof). Can you guess why we can't drop everything and use that smaller language instead? This is a less extreme case of the same logic.

Comment: I suspect it is answerable (thought I don't know the answer myself) - when the language features were included, I don't think the reasoning would have been "why not?"  I suspect there is a reason.

Comment: Why using loops when you can use `if` and `goto`?

Comment: @MathieuImbert: hmm... Good Question, No need for loops ;)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about the typical `for` loop used in for example C/C++.

Though a `for` loop can always be rewritten into a `while` loop, it has a big *readability* advantage: All the loop related properties

- initalization
- testing
- post loop operation (typically an increase or traversing)

can be captured in one line. If you have a longer body with a `while` loop, the whole thing might not fit your screen size, or even if it fits you have to visually parse the code to see what's going on.

In essence, if applicable, the `for` loop captures better the intent of your code.

Comment: Additionally in C++, C#, (and Java too?) a `for` loop can contain the entire scope of a variable declared within the initialisation part of the `for`.  Something which is not possible with a `while` loop.

Comment: @James It's possible, via `{ initialization; while (condition) { ...; step; } }`. But that's even less readable (and wastes indentation).

Comment: Well, most things are possible. For a given value of 'possible'. You could equally argue all mathematical operators are redundant, because you can do everything with a nand operator.

Comment: @James Yeah, but in this case no incredibly sneaky and impractical definition of "possible" is needed -- it's simple enough to remember and type out each time, and equal performance and semantics. It's just inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is in the code readability, at compilation time the `for` loop is translated in a `while` loop with a previous initialization and a following incrementation.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop is used when we know the terminating condition.

`while` loop is generally used if we don't know the terminating condition or better we can say when we don't care what the terminating condition will be...and performance wise both will same

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the condition that makes a loop "a loop", and in both cases the condition is provided by the user (and it's not part of the loop construct translation to machine code) I suspect they exist in different flavors more as a documentation tool than anything else. However the for loop enables you to declare local variables that exist only for the duration of the loop:

```
for (Iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it) {
} // it destroyed here
```

Ofc you can do without all loops; a goto is suficient